# Pass hash and variable to subroutine

Tags: perl

```
my %hash;

my $input2 = "message";

#calling subroutine check_something

$self->check_something (%hash, message => $input2);

sub check_something {

my $self            = shift;
my %p               = @_;
my $message         = $p{message};
my %hash            = @_;

# do some action with the %hash and $input2;

}
```

I build a hash (%hash)  and have another variable which I want to pass into a subroutine. However , inside the subroutine the way I am doing "my %hash = @_" also gets the value of $input2. What should I do to avoid this ?

Answer (score 5):

The @_ is an array so set up your variables as such. If you want to address individual pieces you can address as $_[0]; Pass the hash by ref:

```
$self->check_something (\%hash, {message => $input2});
sub check_something {
my ($self, $ref, $message) = @_;

my %p = %{$ref};
# can reference the value of $input2 through $$message{'message'} or casting $message as a hash my %m = %{$message}; $m{'message'};
# do some action with the %hash and $input2;

}
```

Comment: my %p = %{$ref};  gets me the hash fine.

Comment: Lets say if I want to print the value of $input2 inside the subroutine, how can i do that ?   should i do something like  $message = $_[2] ?

Comment: I forgot one in my dec. it should be my ($self, $ref, $message, $input) = @_; Because the => acts like a comma so you will have a string "message" and whatever $input2 is.

Comment: $self->check_something (%hash, message => $input2);
    sub check_something {
    my ($self, $ref, $message) = @_;
    my %p =   %{$ref};
    my $input2 = $$message{"message"};  
    
    When i run it, I get Cant use string "message" as a Hash ref

Comment: passing $input2 just as a variable when I call the subroutine works fine but I would like to understand how to pass it as a Hash and use it inside the sub

Comment: $self->check_something(\%hash, {"message"=>$input2}); Then treat $message inside check something like the $ref and either cast as a hash or ref using $$message{'message'};

Answer (score 1):

Either you pass first the variable, then the hash, or you pass a reference to the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Perl [flattens subroutine arguments](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION) into a single list--Perl automatically does a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply to all non-prototyped subroutine calls.  So, for the case of `$self->check_something (%hash, message => $input2);` the `%hash` is flattened.

So if:

```
%hash = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );
```

Your sub call is:

```
   $self->check_something( foo => 1, bar => 2, message => $input2 );
```

So, if you want to pass your hash as a separate entity, you need to pass a reference:

```
   # Reference to hash:
   $self->check_something( \%hash, message => $input2 );

   # To pass an anonymous copy:    
   $self->check_something( {%hash}, message => $input2 );

   # To expand hash into an anonymous array:
   $self->check_something( [%hash], message => $input2 );
```

In most cases, you will probably want to do one of the first two examples I showed.

The benefit of the list flattening behavior is that is very easy to build up argument lists programatically.  For example:

```
my %args = (
    foo => 'default',
    bar => 'default_bar',
    baz => 23,
);

$args{foo} = 'purple' if $thingy eq 'purple people eater';

my %result = get_more_args();
@args{ keys %result } = values %result;

my_amazing_sub_call( %args );
```